Question about specific step in proof of Lie-Kolchin (as in Milnes "Algebraic Groups")
The below is taken from Algebraic Groups (page 300-301)

In the last paragraph, the claim is that $H = G(k)$ since otherwise its cosets would disconnect $G(k)$. I would be very happy if someone could expand on the details of this. I mean, I believe the claim here is that $\chi:N \to \mathbb{G}_m \subset \mathbb{A}^1$ is a regular function, so defined by polynomial equations, so that the set $$H = \{g \in G \;|\; g \chi = \chi\}$$ is defined by polynomial equations, and so is closed in the Zariski-topology on $G(k)$, very roughly. But in what sense do the cosets disconnect $G(k)$ if $H \neq G(k)$? My guess is that this is the reasoning:

$[H:G(k)] = n < \infty$ so that $G(k) = \bigsqcup_{i = 1}^{n} g_iH$.
Assuming that each $g_i$ acts as a homeomorphism on $H$, it follows that $g_iH$ is closed for every $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Then also all $g_iH$ is open (in the zariski-topology; it is the complement of a closed set of a union of other [closed] cosets). Therefore the cosets disconnect $G(k)$.


I deleted my answer as your own post contains the same and your arguments are correct.
